# Storing a PDF file in DB with Flask-admin

Tags: python, mongodb, object, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

can I store PDF files in the database, as object or blob, with Flask-Admin?
I do not find any reference in the documentation.

Thanks.
Cheers

Answer (score 10):

Below is a self contained an example of storing files directly in a blob field via Flask-Admin. There is minimal error checking but it should get you going in the right direction.

The important parts of the code:

```
class BlobMixin(object):
    mimetype = db.Column(db.Unicode(length=255), nullable=False)
    filename = db.Column(db.Unicode(length=255), nullable=False)
    blob = db.Column(db.LargeBinary(), nullable=False)
    size = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
```

`BlobMixin` class defines what fields are stored along with the blob data, often it's useful to carry additional  information such as file size, mime type and the file name of the original uploaded file.

```
class Image(db.Model, BlobMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'images'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(length=255), nullable=False, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"name : {name}; filename : {filename})".format(name=self.name, filename=self.filename)
```

`Image` class is the database table that stores the blob (via the BlobMixin). In this instance we are giving each image a unique name that is independent of the uploaded file name.

Class `BlobUploadField(fields.StringField)` is almost a copy of the FileUploadField class from [Flask-Admin](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). There are a few important differences though - we need to know what fields we are using to store the file size, mime type and original file name. These are passed in via the constructor and are used in the `def populate_obj(self, obj, name)` method.

Class `ImageView(ModelView)` is a straightforward Flask-Admin view. Note how the blob field is defined in `form_extra_fields`. We are constructing a `BlobUploadField` and passing in the allowed file extensions list, the size field name, the filename field name and the mime type field name. The names of the fields (size, filename and mimetype) are taken directly from the `BlobMixin` class field names.

```
form_extra_fields = {'blob': BlobUploadField(
    label='File',
    allowed_extensions=['pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'],
    size_field='size',
    filename_field='filename',
    mimetype_field='mimetype'
)}
```

I've add a download link column to the list view with an appropriate column formatter so you can click on the link and download the file.

Code below tested using Python 2.7.9, Flask 0.10.0, Flask-Admin 1.1.0 and Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.0. Uses SQLite in-memory database so the data will be lost upon the flask application being closed.

```
import io
from gettext import gettext
from flask import Flask, send_file
from flask.ext.admin import Admin
from flask.ext.admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from markupsafe import Markup
from werkzeug.datastructures import FileStorage
from wtforms import ValidationError, fields
from wtforms.validators import required
from wtforms.widgets import HTMLString, html_params, FileInput

try:
    from wtforms.fields.core import _unset_value as unset_value
except ImportError:
    from wtforms.utils import unset_value

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///:memory:'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


def build_db():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()


class BlobMixin(object):
    mimetype = db.Column(db.Unicode(length=255), nullable=False)
    filename = db.Column(db.Unicode(length=255), nullable=False)
    blob = db.Column(db.LargeBinary(), nullable=False)
    size = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)


class Image(db.Model, BlobMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'images'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(length=255), nullable=False, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"name : {name}; filename : {filename})".format(name=self.name, filename=self.filename)


class BlobUploadField(fields.StringField):

    widget = FileInput()

    def __init__(self, label=None, allowed_extensions=None, size_field=None, filename_field=None, mimetype_field=None, **kwargs):

        self.allowed_extensions = allowed_extensions
        self.size_field = size_field
        self.filename_field = filename_field
        self.mimetype_field = mimetype_field
        validators = [required()]

        super(BlobUploadField, self).__init__(label, validators, **kwargs)

    def is_file_allowed(self, filename):
        """
            Check if file extension is allowed.

            :param filename:
                File name to check
        """
        if not self.allowed_extensions:
            return True

        return ('.' in filename and
                filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in
                map(lambda x: x.lower(), self.allowed_extensions))

    def _is_uploaded_file(self, data):
        return (data and isinstance(data, FileStorage) and data.filename)

    def pre_validate(self, form):
        super(BlobUploadField, self).pre_validate(form)
        if self._is_uploaded_file(self.data) and not self.is_file_allowed(self.data.filename):
            raise ValidationError(gettext('Invalid file extension'))

    def process_formdata(self, valuelist):
        if valuelist:
            data = valuelist[0]
            self.data = data

    def populate_obj(self, obj, name):

        if self._is_uploaded_file(self.data):

            _blob = self.data.read()

            setattr(obj, name, _blob)

            if self.size_field:
                setattr(obj, self.size_field, len(_blob))

            if self.filename_field:
                setattr(obj, self.filename_field, self.data.filename)

            if self.mimetype_field:
                setattr(obj, self.mimetype_field, self.data.content_type)


class ImageView(ModelView):

    column_list = ('name', 'size', 'filename', 'mimetype', 'download')
    form_columns = ('name', 'blob')

    form_extra_fields = {'blob': BlobUploadField(
        label='File',
        allowed_extensions=['pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'],
        size_field='size',
        filename_field='filename',
        mimetype_field='mimetype'
    )}

    def _download_formatter(self, context, model, name):
        return Markup("<a href='{url}' target='_blank'>Download</a>".format(url=self.get_url('download_blob', id=model.id)))

    column_formatters = {
        'download': _download_formatter,
    }


# download route

@app.route("/download/<int:id>", methods=['GET'])
def download_blob(id):
    _image = Image.query.get_or_404(id)
    return send_file(
        io.BytesIO(_image.blob),
        attachment_filename=_image.filename,
        mimetype=_image.mimetype
    )

# Create admin
admin = Admin(app, name='Admin', url='/')
admin.add_view(ImageView(model=Image, session=db.session, category='Database', name='Images'))


@app.before_first_request
def first_request():
    build_db()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=7777)
```

Comment: pjcunningham thanks!  I found your solution useful! Are you interested in doing PR for Flask-Admin project?

Comment: This worked like magic! Thanks a lot. Can you explain a bit more about how it actually works? populate_obj seems like black magic to me, and it's poorly documented in flask-admin. When does it get called?

Answer (score -2):

Flask-Admin doesn't store anything. It's just a window into the underlying storage.

So yes, you can have `blob` fields in a Flask-Admin app -- as long as the engine of your database supports `blob` types.

In case further explanation is needed, Flask-Admin is not a database. It is an interface to a database. In a flask-admin app, you connect to a pre-existing database. This might be an sqlite database, PostGresSQL, MySQL, MongoDB or any of a variety of databases.