# How to override the admin model creation form in flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, flask-admin

My model (called magazine) has a string field that refers to the location of the image on the hard drive. In flask-admin however, I would like to upload an image to the magazine object instead of a string. Is there a way to specify an image in the model instead of a string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing a PDF file in DB with Flask-admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722132/storing-a-pdf-file-in-db-with-flask-admin)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Don't use flask-admin, create the routes and templates yourself so you will have much more freedom with forms

Comment: Ok, Robert! Thanks for the answer!